# When enabling Water Lock on the Apple Watch, do the hardware buttons also stop responding to input?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

When using an Apple Watch Series 2 or later, there's an option that can be activated from within the Control Center that locks all screen input; this is useful when swimming whilst wearing the Watch, but also prevents accidental taps during everyday use. I'm wondering whether activating this setting also disables input from the hardware buttons - I was mainly thinking the on/off button - it would be useful to know if the Emergency SOS feature can still be activated when it's enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware inputs still work. During waterlock, you'll need to turn the Digital Crown in order to expel the water from the watch and disable waterlock.